# Deserialize Json String not working

Tags: c#, php, json

I want to deserialize a Json string from a php website. Unfortunately every time I try it, it will return null for medianPrice....Why?

```
public class PriceInfo
{
    public string success { get; set; }
    public double lowestPrice { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public string medianPrice { get; set; }
}

WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=" + name;
byte[] html = client.DownloadData(url);
UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
string return_value = utf.GetString(html);
PriceInfo priceInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<PriceInfo>(return_value);
if( Double.Parse(priceInfo.medianPrice) > 0.15 )
{
      string blablu = "hello";
}
```

The Json which returns from the website is the following:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"&#36;0.04","volume":"3,952","median_price":"&#36;0.02"}
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: MedianPrice is declared as an array, the JSON is not an array

Comment: Sorry. was my fault. I also tried without array. It is null also.

Answer (score 0):

I am strongly recommending that you try using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

you will find that it is easier to handle your Jason objects

your code will be like this (**Untested**)

```
PriceInfo defaultCallResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceInfo>(return_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON property is named "median_price" (with an underscore), but your C# property is "medianPrice".

You could use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which will allow you to change the mapping using attributes.

Using Json.NET, decorate your medianPrice property as follows:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "median_price")]
public string medianPrice { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `JavaScriptSerializer` succeeds in parsing your class at all, as the keys hardly match match the class properties.

[`JavaScriperSerializer` is obsolete](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/any-bets-on-whether-or-not-javascriptserializer-will-really-be-obsolete), I'd recommend you use another serializer, such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
public class PriceInfo
{
   [JsonProperty("success")]
   public string Success { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("lowest_price")]
   public double LowestPrice { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("volume")]
   public string Volume { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("median_price")]
   public string MedianPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And when you want to deserialize:

```
PriceInfo priceInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceInfo>(returnValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as mentioned in the other answers, your property names do not match.

So take

```
public class PriceInfo
{

    public string success { get; set; }
    public string lowest_price { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public string median_price { get; set; }
}
```

edit: as mentioned by Yuval, you cannot use JsonProperty with JavaScriptSerializer so you need to stick with the property names from the json.

Then, there is currency information in the json. So you need to get rid of these:

```
string return_value = "{\"success\":true,\"lowest_price\":\"&#36;0.04\",\"volume\":\"3,952\",\"median_price\":\"&#36;0.02\"}";
string return_valueconverted = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(return_value);
PriceInfo priceInfo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<PriceInfo>(return_valueconverted);
priceInfo.lowest_price = priceInfo.lowest_price.TrimStart('$');
priceInfo.median_price = priceInfo.median_price.TrimStart('$');
```

As you can see, this does HtmlDecode these values and afterwards trims the dollar sign from the value.

See more about Html character set here:
http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

Comment: `JsonProperty` wont help him with JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalItzchakov, you are correct. Removed this option.